# Is there an UI Indicator for the Flashlight/Laser?

Tags: battlefield-3

When you have the flashlight or the laser pointer, is there any UI Indicator for whether it is enabled or not?

While it is very obvious with the Flashlight, it would be useful for the Laser.

Comment: Not the other way around? I find it easy to spot the laser, but I can never tell if my flashlight is on or off.

Comment: It depends on the map. Outdoor maps Ste horrible to tell if the flashlight is on, but indoor maps it's really easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no UI indicator telling you whether your laser/flashlight is enabled or not.

In my opinion it's really easy to see if laser is enabled: you will see the beginning of the laser coming out from your gun. And if you use sniper you will see a big blurry red spot in the middle of the scope while aiming.

Answer (score 0):

In case of laser, sometimes (especially in outdoor maps) it is hard to see your laser beam. In this case you can toggle your laser and see that crosshair gets smaller/bigger. When you crosshair is smaller, your laser is on. Hope this trivial info is useful.